# What is the relationship between "late binding" and "inversion of control"?

Tags: design-patterns, oop, inversion-of-control, late-binding

In [his definition](http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/~ram/pub/pub_jf47ht81Ht/doc_kay_oop_en) of OOP, Alan Kay points out he supports "the extreme late-binding of all things". Does his interest in late-binding share the same motivation as people's interest in IoC?

In particular, would it be correct to say that both are motivated by the concept "specify as little as possible, and leave implementation details to be filled in later"?

Comment: I hope you do realize you're question is so vague that no sober person will ever answer it.

Comment: Hm, do you have any suggestions as to how I could be more specific? I'm looking for ties between what Smalltalkers refer to "late binding of all things" and "modern" IoC patterns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by inversion of control - the term has been overloaded to include dependency injection, but they are really different concepts.  IoC originally described a method of controlling program flow, whereas DI is specifically concerned with reducing coupling between types.

That said, it could be argued that all these methods/patterns/philosophies share the same fundamental principle: to lower the cost of change.